# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't recognize MSBuild.exe

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to build my Metro app through the command line using MSBuild.exe, but that exe is not being recognised. Do I need to download the .NET Framework? I am using Visual Studio 2012 for development.

Comment: Are you sure msbuild is on the path?

Comment: Visual Studio should have installed the .NET Framework along with it. Is MSBuild.exe part of your path? At the Windows command line, type `PATH` and post the results. That shows us the current path.

Comment: ok.thanks.MSBuild was not in the PATH .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it was because msbuild is not on your path. You have two options:

1. Add the path to msbuild to the PATH environment variable
2. There should be a "Developer Command Prompt" installed alongside express. This will have all the necessary paths already set so you can use msbuild and any other tools.